# Run time error 1004. Object not defined

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to assign values from one range while treating the range in sheet "field team" as variable set. But getting object object/application defined error
I'm new to VBA (and coding in general), please help me out!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Arr2(1 To 51, 1 To 1) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 51
    Arr2(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, C)
Next i

For i = 1 To 51
If Arr2(i, 1) Then Worksheets("Field Team").Cells(i + 78, C).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Although the answer below looks good, this question would be vastly improved if you indicated which line is giving the error.  You can add a breakpoint and step through line by line until it gives the error.  This goes a long way to identifying the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Small mistake, try as follow:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Arr2(1 To 51, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 51
        Arr2(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, 3)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 51
        If Arr2(i, 1) Then 
             Worksheets("Field Team").Cells(i + 78, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The change here is the `C` became a `3`.  It is worth noting that you can use a column letter for `Cells` if it is in quotes.  So `.Cells(i+1, "C")` would be valid.  This answered would be improved with a description.